# Getting PHP (Valums File Uploader) script to NOT overwrite if file exists

Tags: php

I'm creating a site where you can upload a zip file and we will extract it and provide a method of viewing your html site before viewing it. I can see my main problem is going to be bandwidth right now and that is due to the fact that once you access the [Valums File-Uploader](https://github.com/valums/file-uploader) on our page you can upload infinite files.

I've already changed the script so that it opens a session and grabs the persons username and no matter what they upload it goes in the format of:

```
        if ($this->file->save($uploadDirectory . $_SESSION['myusername'] . '.site.' . $ext)){
```

This makes it so no matter what they upload it gets created in the format of username.site.zip.

I think I need to recode this section, but am not 100% what to change it to - I have tried everything I could think of with no avail:

```
if(!$replaceOldFile){
        /// don't overwrite previous files that were uploaded
        while (file_exists($uploadDirectory . '.' . $_SESSION['myusername'] . '.site.' . $ext)) {
            return array('error'=> 'Could not save uploaded file.' .
            'The upload was cancelled, or server error encountered');
        }
    }
```

Please help me out on this!

Comment: You can answer your own question :-)